# Can any part of AES encrypted blocks be used as PRFed value?

Tags: aes, pseudo-random-function

Suppose we need a PRF whose output space is 255bit.

Then, what I can do with AES with 128-bit security is producing 2 AES blocks that are of 256-bit.

Then, I will remove the most significant bit of one block so that I have 255-bit output.

Is it secure if I remove the top-bit of the one block to make it 127-bit?

Comment: AES is supposed to be a PRP.

Comment: What is the common practice to implement PRF of arbitrary length output?

Comment: Use a good Cryptographic hash function?

Comment: @kelalaka a PRP can als be used as a PRF (that's the infamous "PRP-PRF-Switching Lemma")

Comment: does my implementation work?

Comment: @SEJPM I know, but PRP is a subset of PRF's, right

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, the set of all functions contains the set of all permutations for the same domain and range. Though I'm not sure how I feel about calling PRPs a subset of PRFs.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it secure if I remove the top-bit of the one block to make it 127-bit?

Yes truncating the output of a PRF produces a new PRF, which can be easily seen by a simple reduction. Assume you had an adversary that could break the truncated PRF, then you would forward all queries to the untruncated PRF and truncate the result (which is a perfect simulation) and output whatever your truncated adversary outputs. This constructed adversary wins whenever the truncated adversary wins.

> AES with 128-bit security is producing 2 AES blocks

This is the tricky part. To compose two PRFs - and AES is assumed to be a PRP which can be used as a PRF if you do less than ~$2^{64}$ invocations - you'll need to ensure that for all possible queries the inputs to both calls are unique. Standard ways to achieve this are to use two different, independent keys for the sub-PRFs or to prepend a unique value, e.g. a single fixed bit which is always 0 for the left and always 1 for the right one.

Comment: The success of the adversary in the truncate game isn't related to the size of the output and the size of the truncation?

Comment: @kelalaka hmm, I think $\mathbf{Adv}^{\text{PRF}}_{F}\geq \mathbf{Adv}^{\text{PRF}}_{F'}$ (with $F'$ being the truncated PRF) holds (because the truncated adversary naturally has a lower chance to win (?))